# Line of numbers separated with white space is type of integer in C?

Tags: c, integer

I'm new in C and already feel like bored on its data types.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
   char command[50];

   strcpy( command, "ps -x | wc" );
   int first = pepen(command);
   int two_digit = first; 
   printf("two = %i, three = %d", two_digit, first);

   return(0);
}
```

I want to get first two numbers `88` of `int first`.
I have no idea to which kind of integer `int first` is equal. When I use `%c` instead of `%d` terminal reporting that I `int first` is integer type and using `first[0]` reporting that it is not object. Then what is the type of `first` and
how can I print only first two digits white there is space between them?

Comment: What _are_ you trying to do?  The return value from `system()` is the exit status of the command that is executed.  You don't show what you're running — `command` is uninitialized in the fragment you show.  If you want to read the output, you have to go outside standard C and use functions such as `popen()` and `pclose()` to capture the output from the command.

Comment: I'm trying to print only first two integers '82'. But is integer `first` storing those number as if they were integers? could you show it using `popen()` otherwise?

Comment: You're not showing what the command is doing.  About the only thing that's certain is that `first` does not contain 82 (it could perhaps contain 82 on some systems, but it is pretty unlikely; for example, it won't contain 82 on any Unix-like system I've come across).  If the command writes to its standard output, then you can use `popen()`.  If the command is doing something else, you need to do something different to capture its output.  What is the command you're running and what exactly is it doing?  Which O/S are you using?

Comment: I did update the my code above. For now I need to have this first integer which is '82', further I will use this number to display on screen in other project.

Comment: I'm not sure what `pepen()` is; it isn't the same as [`popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html) which, amongst other things, takes two arguments, as shown in my answer.  Please provide information when asked.  Note that if you only want the line count, you can use `wc -l` instead of `wc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***IF*** (that's a big *if*):

- You are on a Unix-like system, and
- The command you run generates numbers on standard output,

then you can probably use [`popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html) and `pclose()` to run the command and read the output of the command:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char command[] = "echo 82 509 8274";
    FILE *fp = popen(command, "r");
    if (fp != 0)
    {
        int first;
        if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &first) == 1)
            printf("Got %d from the command\n", first);
        pclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```